# Strange Select Box Behaviour in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an issue that is only occurring in Firefox (v.16.0.2), and only on some select boxes. When a select box is clicked on, the dropdown portion appears at the bottom of the page, instead of directly below the select box itself (see image at end of question).

All the boxes are straight HTML, like so:

```
<select name="province" id="Province">
    <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Alberta</option>
    <option value="2">British Columbia</option>
</select>
```

We've got these types of inputs all over our system, but it's only occurring on certain pages - and then only on some of the select boxes on those pages. For instance, if a page has a Province/State select box and a Country select box, only the Province/State one will be broken.

I've compared CSS and Javascript between the pages and select boxes that work and those than don't, and I can't see any differences. Has anyone seen this type of issue before?

[image: Image showing select box oddity]

Edit: If I have Firebug open, the the dropdown portion jumps around (down to the bottom of the page and then back to the select box itself), but it does return and act normally.

Comment: I hearing lot of these select box issues recently in firefox version 16, unfortunately I don't know the solution sorry

Comment: Are you using frames anywhere? I'm wondering if it is related to this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=807174

Comment: Check suggestions here http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/940712

Comment: @user868766 - Thanks, but that's not quite the issue we're experiencing.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos - nope, no frames. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug fix for this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=807174. It looks like the fix is in their beta release as of 11/05. I'd imagine it'll be available soon.

Comment: Looks like that only applies to pages w/ frames, which we don't have. Thanks though.